SpringBoot 3, SQLite - IndexOutOfBoundsException when loading Instants
I am using SpringBoot 3 to access a SQLite database. My problem is, that when fetching entities parallely, I get a random ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in a Java class that parses a date.
SpringBoot 3.2.5
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.42.2.0</version>
</dependency>

The dialect is set to spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect
My Java class looks like this:
public class SomeTable implements Serializable {
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME_CREATED = "CREATED";
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME_MODIFIED = "MODIFIED";
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME_IP = "IP";
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME = "USERNAME";

  @Id
  @Column(length = 36)
  protected String id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "created")
  private Instant created;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "modified")
  private Instant modified;
}

The table looks like this:
CREATE TABLE "some_table" (
    "id"    varchar(36) NOT NULL,
    "created"   timestamp NOT NULL,
    "modified"  timestamp NOT NULL
);

This is the stacktrace I am getting:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 18 out of bounds for length 13
at java.base/sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Unknown Source)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getTimestamp(JDBC3ResultSet.java:490)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTimestamp(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.TimestampUtcAsJdbcTimestampJdbcType$2.doExtract(TimestampUtcAsJdbcTimestampJdbcType.java:103)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:44)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.getCurrentRowValue(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:302)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.getJdbcValue(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:119)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.basic.BasicResultAssembler.extractRawValue(BasicResultAssembler.java:52)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.basic.BasicResultAssembler.assemble(BasicResultAssembler.java:59)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.DomainResultAssembler.assemble(DomainResultAssembler.java:33)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.extractConcreteTypeStateValues(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:1081)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeEntityInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:838)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeEntity(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:813)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:799)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.initializeInstance(InitializersList.java:70)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:109)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:181)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:209)
at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:83)
at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:76)
at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:145)
at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:117)
at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:75)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3748)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3737)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:604)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromCacheOrDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:590)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:560)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:544)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadWithRegularProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:290)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:242)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:111)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:68)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1222)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1068)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntitySelectFetchInitializer.initializeInstance(EntitySelectFetchInitializer.java:195)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.initializeInstance(InitializersList.java:70)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:109)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:203)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33)
at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:209)
at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:83)
at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:76)
at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:65)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$2(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:137)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:362)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:303)
at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509)
at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:120)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:383)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:277)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy229.findAll(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy229.findAll(Unknown Source)
at com.my.project.services.SomeTableService.getSomeTable(AbstractNetworkRoutingService.java:97)

Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 27 out of bounds for length 13
at java.base/sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.Calendar.setTimeInMillis(Unknown Source)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getTimestamp(JDBC3ResultSet.java:490)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getTimestamp(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.TimestampUtcAsJdbcTimestampJdbcType$2.doExtract(TimestampUtcAsJdbcTimestampJdbcType.java:103)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:44)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.getCurrentRowValue(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:302)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.getJdbcValue(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:119)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.basic.BasicResultAssembler.extractRawValue(BasicResultAssembler.java:52)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.basic.BasicResultAssembler.assemble(BasicResultAssembler.java:59)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.DomainResultAssembler.assemble(DomainResultAssembler.java:33)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.extractConcreteTypeStateValues(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:1081)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeEntityInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:838)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeEntity(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:813)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.AbstractEntityInitializer.initializeInstance(AbstractEntityInitializer.java:799)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.initializeInstance(InitializersList.java:70)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:109)
at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:86)
...
com.my.project.services.SomeTableService.getSomeTable(AbstractNetworkRoutingService.java:97)

The dates in the table look like this:

We tried to use a custom converter that uses Instant.ofEpochMillis() but the problem still appeared.
My current assumption is a race condition. Limiting the number of connections to 1 via Spring settings solves the problem - but having to do that because of this seems just wrong, performance-wise this is not optimal so I was thinking someone might have an idea on some other way.

I would suggest use Date instead of Instance
@NotNull
@Column(name = "modified")
private Date modified;
public String getModified() {
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
return formatter.format(modified);
}

Can you share the date in question? In general it strikes me odd that the Sqlite dialect is using Calendar etc. to parse a date to Instant. As far as I know Sqlite internally stores epoch milliseconds as a string so the dialect should be able to call Instant.ofEpochMilli() or so. Can you check what version of Hibernate and any additional Sqlite dialect library you're using?

I added the information to the question. I find it weird too. We tried to use a custom converter that uses Instant.ofEpochMillis() but the problem still appeared.

@AlpeshSorathiya I consider that the worst idea I have have read for a long time. Replacing the modern Instant with the badly designed and decade-long outdated Date class would be a huge step backward and may well not help with the problem.

Looks to me like a bug somewhere. sun.util.calendar.BaseCalendar.getCalendarDateFromFixedDate() does long month1 = jan1 + ACCUMULATED_DAYS_IN_MONTH[month]; where ACCUMULATED_DAYS_IN_MONTH has length 13, so I guess this is where it goes wrong. How it manages to calculate the 0-based month number as 18 I can’t tell.

I’m curious how you may reproduce the problem with a custom converter.

I assumed that the problem happened, when converting a java.sql.Timestamp to java.time.Instant and added an ``jakarta.persistence.AttributeConverter` between those two. I validated that it was actually used in an integration test (which it did).
We provoked the bug by running a load test with parallel requests and managed to have it happen quite consistently

May sound like a race condition? Since you mention load. GregorianCalendar (also appearing in your stack trace) is not thread safe, so just speculating, if SQLite uses one from multiple threads, the error may occur. In my quick test I got ClassCastException sometimes when using a GregorianCalendar from multiple threads.

This is also my current assumption. Limiting the number of connections to 1 via Spring settings solves the problem - but having to do that because of this seems just wrong, performance-wise this is not optimal so I was thinking someone might have an idea on some other way

Someone voted to close with reason "Needs debugging details". Debugging details would usually mean [mre] and desired and observed result. I believe that desired result is clear, observed result fully reported. The example is close enough to minimal and could be reproduced with a little effort. Please leave this question open.

I suspect that the bug is in Hibernate TimestampUtcAsJdbcTimestampJdbcType source code. Line 103 (the line mentioned in your stack trace) reads final Timestamp timestamp = rs.getTimestamp( paramIndex, UTC_CALENDAR );, passing private static final Calendar UTC_CALENDAR = Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) ); as argument. This Calendar instance is shared between all threads. It’s got to go wrong. :-(

That looks pretty spot-on! Can I force hibernate to use a custom implementation?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This is a bug now reported to Hibernate: HHH-18239. We implemented a custom type as a temporary solution:
/**
 * This is a custom implementation of a Hibernate type, that maps a {@link Types#TIMESTAMP} to a
 * {@link java.time.Instant}. This is necessary, because of this bug in Hibernate:
 * <a href="https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-18239">Hibernate ORM Jira HHH-18239</a>.
 */
public class CustomThreadSafeInstantType implements UserType<Instant> {

  @Override
  public int getSqlType() {
    return Types.TIMESTAMP;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<Instant> returnedClass() {
    return Instant.class;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Instant instant, Instant j1) {
    return Objects.equals(instant, j1);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(Instant instant) {
    return instant.hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public Instant nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, int i, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor, Object o) throws SQLException {
    var timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(i);

    if (timestamp == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return timestamp.toInstant();
  }

  @Override
  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Instant instant, int i, SharedSessionContractImplementor sharedSessionContractImplementor)
      throws SQLException {
    if (instant == null) {
      preparedStatement.setNull(i, Types.TIMESTAMP);
      return;
    }

    preparedStatement.setTimestamp(i, Timestamp.from(instant));
  }

  @Override
  public Instant deepCopy(Instant instant) {
    return instant;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable disassemble(Instant instant) {
    return instant;
  }

  @Override
  public Instant assemble(Serializable serializable, Object o) {
    return (Instant) serializable;
  }


}

This type is used like so:
public class SomeTable implements Serializable {
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME_CREATED = "CREATED";
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME_MODIFIED = "MODIFIED";
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME_IP = "IP";
  private static final String COLUMN_NAME_USERNAME = "USERNAME";

  @Id
  @Column(length = 36)
  protected String id;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "created")
  @Type(CustomThreadSafeInstantType.class)
  private Instant created;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "modified")
  @Type(CustomThreadSafeInstantType.class)
  private Instant modified;
}

